# Continuous extension of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Can anybody help me with this problem?

> Justify whether the following statement is true or false:
>
> Every continuous function on $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See what happens if you take the function

$$f:\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]:\to[0,1]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x>\frac{\sqrt2}2\\\\
0,&\text{if }x<\frac{\sqrt2}2\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I have got it.f(x)=1/(x^2-0.5) will also work.Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Ester: You’re very welcome.

Comment: just to add a bit, you can for sure tell that a continuous extension exists if the subset $A\subset[0,1]$  you're extending from is closed (though it's not a necessary condition)

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it does; that’s a consequence of the [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

To add to Brian's answer, if $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $D$ is dense in $X$ and $f : D \rightarrow Y$ is a uniformly continuous function where $Y$ is a complete, metric space, then $f$ has a unique extension to $X$ and the extended function is also uniformly continuous.

In particular, in your case, every *uniformly continuous* function can be extended to a *uniformly continuous* function on the reals.